# install salt-minion throw Error: Package: salt-2018.3.3-1.el7.noarch (salt-latest) Requires: python-psutil

Tags: salt-stack

I have installed python-psutil with pip and can use it in python.
but still install failed.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Your question should include all relevant details and should be formatted correctly, in particular, post your error as text (not as image).

Comment: Are you actually using el7? The Salt repo needs to be the correct one for your system, so all the required yum packages are available.

Answer (score -1):

Salt requires some python modules to be installed before installing Salt. So just try after installing the given python dependency module into your machine.

Command :   **pip install psutil**

Reference - https://pypi.org/project/psutil/